# Approve contract on behalf of user?

Tags: dapps

I would like to have a streamlined UI UX and not have a user approve and then transferFrom.

Would it be possible to have a contract method that approves a USDC withdrawal on behalf of the user? I'm thinking something along the lines of (coded in vyper for simplicity):

```
def withdraw(_amount: uint256)->bool:
    ERC20(USDC_address).approve(self,MAX_UINT256)  #defining the smart contract as the spender of the User's USDC
    ERC20(USDC_address).transferFrom(msg.sender,self,_amount)
    return True
```

This would make it easier for a user to deposit and reduce the fees the user has to pay to deposit USDC on the contract as would not require the user to first send one transaction for approve() and another for Transferfrom()

Comment: not possible with ERC20. the approve function should be called by the user directly in the erc20 original contract (USDC)

Comment: You could use ERC20Permit for future token (https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2612 and the OZ integration). Unfortunately, it’s far from being widely adopted for existing ones